# Cronjob Keeps Sending Multiple Emails

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, server, cron

I've been developing a website where users create complaints about brands. The problem is that I want to send the users a reminder email and notification after 3 days of creating their complaints. And I want to send this email once. That's why I checked if the reminder has been sent before.

This code works fine on localhost and sends only one email and notification. But it keeps sending multiple emails and notifications (sometimes 40-50) in a minute on Ubuntu server. The code works multiple times without executing codes down below. Does anyone know why I have this problem?

COMPLAINTREMINDER.php:

```php
protected $signature = 'complaints:reminder';

public function handle()
{
    $complaints = Complaints::with('author')->whereIn('status', ['now_active', 'answered'])->where('approved_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subHour(72))->get();

    foreach($complaints as $complaint) {
        $subject = "random subject";
        $text = "randomtext";
        $textPanel = "Text for notification panel";

        if ($complaint->is_reminder_sent == 0) {
            $this->sendMailByZoho($complaint->author->email, $subject, $text);
            $this->sendPanelNotification($complaint->author, $textPanel, 'memberNewComplaint', 'type');
            $complaint->update(['is_reminder_sent' =>  '1']);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

KERNEL.php:

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('complaints:reminder')->everyMinute();
}
```

CRONTAB:

```bash
* * * * * cd /path_to_my_project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Please check if single email has multiple complains received. There could be a case that for same email there are multiple records in the database which thus it is sending multiple emails.

Comment: Try just delay your mail above a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
$complaint->update(['is_reminder_sent' =>  '1']);
```

Is this line working?

I would have used:

```
$complaint->is_reminder_sent = 1;
$complaint->save();
```

Comment: Yes. This line is working and the is_reminder_sent value is updated. But emails are already sent multiple times before this value is updated. Let's suppose this code isn't working. I've tried with 2 data. The code should send 2 emails for 2 complaints even if the value isn't updated and terminate foreach loop. But it does not. It sent almost 50 email for two complaints.

Comment: If you `dd($complaints)` before for each and run manually what do you see? Just two complaints?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Updating cron worked for me.